# UnityのPost processingのエフェクト適用に関する問題

Tags: windows, unity2d

初めまして。Unityを使用していて不明点が出たので、質問させていただきます。

Unityで、Post processingを適用して、Bloom効果を画面全体に適用したいのですが、Scene上では適用できているのですが、Game上(Buildを含む)では適用されません。何が原因なのでしょうか？
Game上でも、Sceneと同様、Bloom効果を適用したいです。

因みに、2Dでゲーム制作を行っています。
回答を、宜しくお願い致します。